# Exception thrown when parsing data

Tags: java, parsing, localdate

Sorry if this is a rookie question, but I have the following problem: every time I try to parse a string into a `LocalDate` type, with a specific format (ddMMyyy) I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06071994' could not be parsed at index 2
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at jujj.main(jujj.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

At first I thought that maybe I did something wrong in a different part of the code and I tried to isolate just the part where I'm doing the parsing to test it, but no luck. This is the test code:

```
String in = "06071994";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd MM yyyy" );
LocalDate BirthDay = LocalDate.parse ( in, format );
System.out.println ( in );
```

Later Edit: I tried different formats: "dd/MM/yyyy" , "dd-MM-yyyy", "ddMMyyyy", they still didn't work.

Comment: maybe you have to use the pattern ""ddMMyyyy" isntead of " dd MMM yyyy"? I think the formatter expects the empty spaces of your pattern to occur in the target string the way you used it.

Comment: MMM stands for JAN, FEB etc., use MM

Comment: Hey, thanks or the quick response! :D I tried to use it like that, and it gives me the same message. I also tried to use"dd/MM/yyyÿ" and "dd-MM-yyyy" patterns. Sadly it still gives me the same message. To be fair, my laptop is kinda old and running on Windows 7, and I had weird errors just appear and dissapear with me doing nothing else but restarting it. This time however nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: I also tried using just MM, I still get the same message.

Comment: You may have inadvertently entered a non-printing character into the string `"06071994"`. Try deleting that line completely and re-entering it.

Comment: @TardisBug Look closely to what you are trying to parse. You are putting separator characters in between your pattern, but your input string doesn't contain any. The correct pattern here is `ddMMyyyy`.

Comment: @ MC Emperor Thank you, that was the problem. :)

Comment: One more thing – you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class FormatDate {

public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    String in = "06071994";
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    LocalDate BirthDay = LocalDate.parse(in, format);
    System.out.println(BirthDay);
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**: Problem with the code was that the input was in the format ddMMyyyy(06071994) and the format was **dd MM yyyy** (should have been ddMMyyyy). So now parser sees that input and format to parse are not same hence it throws error.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed and why.  A code dump by itself is not very useful to future readers and doesn’t do much to help people learn.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I have explained the problem, do let me know if not able to understand

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your pattern does not match your string.

Your string contains no spaces while your pattern does.

Your string contains a two digit month while your pattern is expecting a three letter abbreviation of the month name.

Try the following code:

```java
String in = "06071994";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "ddMMyyyy" );
LocalDate BirthDay = LocalDate.parse ( in, format );
System.out.println ( BirthDay );
```

All the valid patterns are detailed and explained in the *javadoc* of class [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)